# jest how set file pattern in package.json script

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have in packadge.json

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest"
},
```

I want to test all files match pattern

```
 front/**/*.test.js
```

but if

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest \"front/**/*.test.js\""
},
```

I've got an error

```
Invalid testPattern front/**/*.test.js supplied. Running all tests instead.
```

So, how could I pass file names pattern to jest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#jest-regexfortestfiles) you are supposed to use a regex for your pattern. So in your case you probably would write something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest \"front/.*\\.test\\.js\""
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the `testRegex` parameter in your jest config to set a filename pattern:

```
testRegex: 'front/.*\.test\.js$'
```

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testregex-string).

Comment: the question was how to set file pattern via packedge.json script

Comment: I agree, @ghost23's answer is the right one for this question.

Comment: In the lastests versions of `jest` you can write the config right in the `package.json` using field `jest`.
EXAMPLE: `"jest": { "testRegex": ".*\\.test\\.spec.ts$" }`